# I have no furnace, only electric blowing heaters. How do I get ventilation?

Tags: hvac, ventilation

I have a 100 years old building with a store on the main floor.  Since the building was built over 100 years old there is no ducting whatsoever.  There is also no furnace.  In the summer we just hook up an air conditioner through one of the windows.  In the winter we have a heater blowing the air.

Is an HVAC needed to get ventilation?  Or can I just purchase an Air Exchanger?  I assume I now need to install ducting in the store?  What is the best solution?  Of course the HVAC companies are going to sell me their latest and greatest products out there.

Comment: Will a ductless Mini-Split System solve my problem?

Comment: Unless major anti-infiltration work has been done recently, a building that old should provide adequate fresh air just by natural infiltration. If you have some unusual activity requiring more ventilation, or if it would just make you feel better, adding ventilation is an option. You need to determine how much ventilation you need in order to decide on a system.

Comment: Do you have access to the roof and a corridor from the roof to the store?  That is, can you install a roof top unit and plumb ducts down to the store?